# Images not saving to temporary folder but saved to Database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code with the aim of saving images/upload to a temporary folder in my project root directory. It is expected that the path of the temporary folder be saved to database and the image saved to the temporary folder

I discover the images are not saving to temporary folder rather save directly to the database.

I am using CodeIgniter

***Controller***

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ArticleController extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if (!$this->session->userdata('login_id'))
             return redirect("LoginController");
            $this->load->model('ArticleModel');
            $this->load->model('CategoryModel');
            $this->load->model('UserModel');
            $data = array(); 
    }

    public function addarticle(){
        $data['title'] = 'eBlog Admin Portal - Add Article';
        $data['header'] = $this->load->view('include/header', $data, TRUE);
        $data['sidebar'] = $this->load->view('include/sidebar', '', TRUE);
        $data['categoryData'] = $this->CategoryModel->getCategory();
        $data['userData'] = $this->UserModel->getuser();
        $data['articleadd'] = $this->load->view('include/articleadd', $data, TRUE);
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('include/footer', '', TRUE);
        $this->load->view('addarticle', $data);
    }

    public function addArticleForm(){
        //check whether user upload picture

        if(!empty($_FILES['image_path']['upload_path'])){
            $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/images/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|';
            $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['image_path']['upload_path'];

            //load upload library and initialize configuration
            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload('image_path')){
                $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                $image_path = $uploadData['file_name'];
                }else{
                $image_path = '';
                }

        }
        $data['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
        $data['content'] = $this->input->post('content');
        $data['category_id'] = $this->input->post('category_id');
        $data['written'] = $this->input->post('written');
        $data['featured'] = $this->input->post('featured');
        $data['image_path'] = $this->input->post('image_path');
        $title = $data['title'];
        $content = $data['content'];
        $category_id = $data['category_id'];
        $written = $data['written'];
        $title = $data['featured'];
        $image_path = $data['image_path'];
        if (empty($title) && empty($content) && empty($category_id) && empty($written) && empty($featured) && empty($title)) {
            $sdata = array();
            $sdata['msg'] = '<span style="color:red">Filed must not be empty</span>';
            $this->session->set_flashdata($sdata);
            redirect("ArticleController/addarticle");
        }else {
            $this->ArticleModel->saveArticle($data);
            $sdata = array();
            $sdata['msg'] = '<span style="color:green">Article added successfully!</span>';
            $this->session->set_flashdata($sdata);
            redirect("ArticleController/addarticle");
        }
    }
    

}
```

***Model***

```
<?php
class ArticleModel extends CI_Model{

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function saveArticle($data){
   $this->db->insert('articles', $data);
}
}
```

***View***

```
<h2>Add Article </h2>
        <hr/>

     <?php
        $msg = $this->session->flashdata('msg');
        if(isset($msg)){
            echo $msg;
        }
    ?>

        
    <div class="panel-body" style="width:600px;">
        <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>ArticleController/addArticleForm" method="post" 'enctype' = 'multipart/form-data'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control span12" placeholder="Article Title" required="1">
            </div>
           

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Category</label>
                <select name="category_id" class="form-control span12" required="1">
                <option value="">Select Article Category</option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($categoryData as $sdata) {
                ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $sdata->id ; ?>"><?php echo $sdata->name; ?></option>

                <?php } ?>
                </select>
               
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Written By</label>
                <select name="written" class="form-control span12" required="1">
                <option value="">Select Article Writer</option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($userData as $udata) {
                ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $udata->login_id; ?>"><?php echo $udata-> fullname; ?></option>

                <?php } ?>
                </select>
               
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Featured</label>
                <select name="featured" class="form-control span12" required="1">
                <option value="">Select Article featured</option>
                <?php

                    for($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++) {
                ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>

                <?php } ?>
                </select>
               
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Image</label>
                <input type="file"name="image_path" class="form-control span12"placeholder="Chose Image"  required="1">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Content</label>
                <input type="text"name="content" class="form-control span12"placeholder="Article content"  required="1">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit"class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"> 
            </div>
               
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: what is this? you haven't even uploaded the right code! make your question more focused than this don't expect anyone to read this whole code. specifically tell us what went wrong and where it went wrong. this is too broad.

Comment: Thanks @waanofi

I want images/uploads to save to this part uploads/images/ in the project root directory but it is not.

Comment: Start by adding a space between the attributes type="file"  and name="image_path". That's invalid html.

Comment: check for the folder permission